# jBPM - Running processes in separate threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jbpm

I am trying to run jBPM process in separate threads, using jBPM 6.2. Therefore I created a class named `WorkflowThread` and start a new workflow thread each time I need a new process to be run. The code of the class is this:

```
public WorkflowThread(KieSession session, String workflowID, Map<String, Object> arguments) {
    this.session = session;
    this.workflowID = workflowID;
    this.arguments = arguments;
    this.workflowInstance = this.session.createProcessInstance(workflowID, arguments);
}

public void run(){
    if(this.workflowInstance.getState() == ProcessInstance.STATE_PENDING){
        this.session.startProcessInstance(this.workflowInstance.getId());
    }else{
        try {
            throw new Exception("The process with id "+this.workflowInstance.getId()+" is not pending but in state "+this.workflowInstance.getState());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The calling code is:

```
WorkflowThread thread = new WorkflowThread(this.ksession, workflowID, arguments);
thread.start();
```

However, despite the fact that I check the state of the process before trying to start it (I check that it has not started yet), I get an exception:

> Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A process instance can only be started once
>       at org.jbpm.process.instance.impl.ProcessInstanceImpl.start(ProcessInstanceImpl.java:233)
>       at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.start(WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.java:389)
>       at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcessInstance(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:195)
>       at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcessInstance(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:204)
>       at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.startProcessInstance(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1911)
>       at welcome.auth.workflowmanager.WorkflowThread.run(WorkflowThread.java:43)

What am I doing wrong? Is there an alternative that can be used in order to ensure execution of workflow processes in separate threads?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming to jBPM [sources](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-flow/src/main/java/org/jbpm/process/instance/impl/ProcessInstanceImpl.java#L233) you have STATE mismatches. This looks like a Race Condition. Howewer, I don't have experience with jBPM, so maybe I am wrong.

Comment: I think you are totally right. I have also seen this source code. I don't see an error any more. This implies a racing condition. I will wait if there is a more comprehensive answer on how this should be properly done and if there is not I will mark your answer as the right one. Thank you very much for your help.